# Prove that if $L$ is regular, then $\mathcal{L}(L)$ must be regular

Tags: formal-languages

Let $\Sigma_n = \{0, 1, ... , n-1\}$.  Suppose $L \subseteq$ $\Sigma^*_n$, and let

$\mathcal{L}(L) = \{ x \in L : x \text{ is the lexicographically largest among all strings of length } |x| \text{ in } L \}$.  For example, $\mathcal{L}(\{0,1\}^*) = 1^*$ and $\mathcal{L}(\epsilon \cup 1(0 \cup 01)^*) = (10)^*(\epsilon \cup 1)$.  Prove that if $L$ is regular, then so is $\mathcal{L}(L)$.

Below is my attempt at proving this.

Define alphabet $\gamma = \{(n_1,n_2) : n_1,n_2 \in \Sigma_n\}$.  Define morphism $h : \gamma^* \to \Sigma^*_n$ as $h((n_1,n_2)) = n_1n_2$ for all $(n_1,n_2) \in \gamma$.

Define morphism $h_1 : \gamma^* \to \{1 \cup 2\}^*$ as

$h_1((n_1,n_2)) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 
1 & \quad \text{ if $n_1 > n_2$}\\
2 & \quad \text{ if $n_2 > n_1$}\\
\epsilon & \quad \text{ if $n_1 = n_2$}
\end{array} \right.$

Define the substitution $s : \gamma* \to \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*_n)$ to be $s((n_1,n_2)) = \{n_1\}$ for all $(n_1,n_2) \in \gamma$

1. Perfect shuffle $L$ with itself.  Call the resulting language $L_{ps}$.
2. Compute $L_1 = s(h_1^{-1}(1\{1,2\}^* \cup \epsilon) \space \cap h^{-1}(L_{ps}))$
3. Repeat 1 and 2 with $L_1$

Repeat 1, 2, 3 indefinitely.  The resulting language $L_1$ will be $\mathcal{L}(L)$.

I think the problem with the above is that I'd have to repeat these steps infinitely many times for the case that $L$ is infinite.

Comment: You might want to try the algorithm on a few examples, to see if it seems to converge or not. If you manage to find an example in which it doesn't converge, then you know it doesn't work. Otherwise, you can try to prove that it always converges.

Comment: Also asked (and answered) on cs.se: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30391/prove-that-if-l-is-regular-then-so-is-mathcalbl.